# The emulator wont install my app In flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, android-emulator

### In flutter after I downloaded the android studio and the SDK the JDK and everything, when I create an app it won't get installed in the emulator, the app code has no errors on it but when I run it throw the emulator it won't work but the app runs just fine when I run it throw my phone,
the emulator runs but it won't accept installing the application and any other app;
This is the error :

`Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.

> NDK at C:\Users\abddo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

Answer (score 0):

What operating system are you using, windows or mac? Also, what text editor are you using? Because for mac, you will need to install Xcode, which is the only way for you to get a simulator for flutter other than the web. If you are using windows, one of the only choices is to install Android Studio and select an emulator from there.

Comment: I'm using win10,

Comment: I already have an android studio and already installed the emulator but for some reason, it won work with me.

Comment: On your Android Studio, click File > Settings > Tools > Emulator. Then select Launch in a tool window and click OK. If the Emulator window didn't automatically appear, open it by clicking View > Tool Windows > Emulator